# symfony2 forms with add row button

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form in Symfony2 and I want to give the user an option to add a row to it, in case there's more information they want to provide. I know in JavaScript you can do this, is there a way to do it in symfony2 using the framework?

If not, what's the best possible way around it? With all the validation and everything, not finding any viable option while searching on Google... Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add a dynamic field to your form? There's a very infomative article about this actually; I found it really useful implementing something similar:

http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/finally-through-symfony2-forms-and-collectiontype-make-it-dynamic/

He also created an example bundle:

https://github.com/khepin/ProductBundle

Comment: Hi. Hmm..Not that I'm aware. I've used this article to help me with similar implementation, but it's not a public site. Have you tried using the ProductBundle bundle in a dev installation of Symfony or anything like that?

Comment: The ProductBundle was just intended to be copied and tried by other people for their own needs.
It just shows the basic functionality outlined in the article.

Most importantly, this is now all part of the cookbook as well.

Comment: cool. noted! cheers. oh and thanks for that original article - super useful :)